# Building and pushing Spring Boot maven plugin docker image in Gitlab CI

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gitlab-ci

I'm using Gitlab CI to build my Spring Boot project image and push the image to the container registry.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like the following :

```
stages:
  - buildImage

project-build:
  stage: buildImage
  image: openjdk:8u282-jdk
  script:
    - ./mvnw verify
    - ./mvnw spring-boot:build-image
  tags:
    - docker
```

This configuration fails because the docker image needs to have the docker exec to push the image to the container registry.
I tried the same configuration using `image: docker`, but it fails because maven needs java to run.

So in order to use the `./mvnw spring-boot:build-image` command, I need both java and docker to be present in my java image.

I don't know of any image that contains both.

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A colleague gave me a hint and I thought I would share it with everyone else.

You can, when you register your Gitlab runner, give it access to your docker dameon using socket binding.
You can then use it in a non-docker image.

The [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-socket-binding) explains this.

For the reference, I used the following command to register my runner:

`gitlab-runner register --non-interactive --url https://<my-gitlab>/ --registration-token <my-token> --executor docker --docker-image docker:19.03 --docker-volumes /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: Nice find, thanks for sharing. Just for clarification, `./mvnw spring-boot:build-image` does not need Docker in the image where it runs, but it does require access to a Docker daemon when building the image (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image-docker-daemon).

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you could take a look at Jib: https://www.baeldung.com/jib-dockerizing. It allows you to build and push a docker image without having a docker daemon running. It adds a plugin dependency and some configuration but it would allow you to use only the jdk image.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know of Jib but I wanted to use spring solution to package the image for me without using a Dockerfile.